# Make RecyclerView item grow to fullscreen with transition/animation

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, kotlin, transition

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    ........

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to make an item grow to fullscreen on click but transition just grows in size as element from the list:

```
view.setOnClickListener {
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(it as ViewGroup)
    it.layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    it.requestLayout()
}
```

How to achieve it to scale fullscreen and occupy the screen as independent element nevermind the recyclerview?